# how to fetch base url from the given url using java

Tags: java, jtidy, base-url

I am trying to fetch base URL using java. I have used jtidy parser in my code to fetch the title. I am getting the title properly using jtidy, but I am not getting the base url from the given URL.

I have some URL as input:

```
String s1 = "http://staff.unak.is/andy/GameProgramming0910/new_page_2.htm";
String s2 = "http://www.complex.com/pop-culture/2011/04/10-hottest-women-in-fast-and-furious-movies";
```

From the first string, I want to fetch `"http://staff.unak.is/andy/GameProgramming0910/"` as a base URL and from the second string, I want `"http://www.complex.com/"` as a base URL.

I am using code:

```
URL url = new URL(s1);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
Document doc = new Tidy().parseDOM(in, null);
String titleText = doc.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getFirstChild()
.getNodeValue();
```

I am getting `titletext`, but please can let me know how to get base URL from above given URL?

Comment: What rules would tell you that `http://www.complex.com/` is the base url and not `http://www.complex.com/pop-culture/2011/04/`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try to use the java.net.URL class, it will help you:

For the second case, that it is easier, you could use new URL(s2).getHost();

For the first case, you could get the host and also use getFile() method, and remove the string after the last slash ("/"). something like: (code not tested)

```
URL url = new URL(s1);
String path = url.getFile().substring(0, url.getFile().lastIndexOf('/'));
String base = url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getHost() + path;
```

Comment: I voted up, but it seems to me the third statement should be:
String base = url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getHost() + path;

Comment: I ***THINK*** that URL getProtocol() returns the "://", but I havent tested :(

Comment: @Pih at least in Java 6, it doesn't. You must add it. Think that "://" is not part of the protocol name.

Comment: url string needs check if it has protocol else malformed url exception is thrown.

Comment: Looks like in the event of port being different than default, it's better to use url.getAuthority() rather than getHost().
info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

Comment: also better to use getPath() instead of getFileName(). getFileName() also returns the query part and that could contain many slashes ...

Answer (score 11):

You use the java.net.URL class to resolve relative URLs.

For the first case: removing the filename from the path:

```
new URL(new URL(s1), ".").toString()
```

For the second case: setting the root path:

```
new URL(new URL(s2), "/").toString()
```